# find if a random number belongs to a distribution

Tags: standard-deviation

It might be a very simple one -

Given a mean and a standard deviation, is there any formula, to calculate if a random number could belong to the distribution?

For example , a mean of 1.65 and a standard deviation of 0.65. Could 1.9 belong to the area that has more than 0.8 likelihood? Is there any formula to find this out?

EDIT after comments:

By substituting mean, standard deviation and the random number in the below equation, would it be possible to get the probability of the occurence of a random number ( x )  in the distribution. 
$$ P(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}e^{ - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{ 2\sigma^2 }} $$

Another question is what exactly does the gaussian bell curve tell us? The x axis are the continous numbers and the y axis is the probability, and  the area under the curve should be equal to 1. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: How do you define "belonging to distribution"? With non-zero probability anything in $-\infty$ to $\infty$ "belongs" to normal distribution.

Comment: @Tim above 0.8 probability.. for example , a mean of 1.65 and a standard deviation of 0.65. Would 1.9 lie in an area that has more than  0.8 likelihood?

Comment: "Likelihood" has a particular technical meaning in statistics that I doubt you intend here (it's a function of the parameter(s), rather than the data, for one thing). A single value from a continuous distribution has zero probability $(P(X=a)=0$), so you can't mean that. On the other hand I don't necessarily think you mean density either, since density may be arbitrarily high ($f(a)$ is not a probability and may exceed any specific finite value). Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Glen_b ok, i will try to clarify. I have a set of data that are normally distributed.  Ofcourse, the distribution consists of numbers and how many times the numbers occur in the distribution.. So a histogram can be created and this histogram matches a bell curve, because the data is normally distributed. Now, my question is given a mean and a standard deviation, would it be possible to know if any number was a part of the distribution ? I saw the Gaussian equation and maybe thats the solution of my problem?  ( please see my updated question )

Comment: @infoclogged sorry, but this is still quite unclear, you can define such area, that the values in the area have probability 0.8, say $-\infty < X < c$ or $c < X < \infty$ for some $c$ and the value of interest lies in the area, but this wouldn't prove anything...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general and leaves a lot of room for speculation.

First, mean and standard deviation are not sufficient to specify a probability measure.

Other than that, unless the random number is outside of the support of the distribution (like you sample 0.523 - in which case it was not a discrete probability measure on the positive integers.) you can not really say whether that one sample came from a particular probability measure or not.

If you had many samples, a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) may be appropriate.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: The answer is still no. As I said, mean and standard deviation are not even sufficient to specify the probability measure.

Comment: Not the answer to your question but related is the Chebyshev inequality which tell you the minimum amount of the distribution that is contained within k standard deviations of the mean. One thing it tells you is that there exists at least one distribution for which none of possible values for the distribution are within one standard deviation of the mean.